# How to get HTML elment with help of ID?

Tags: javascript

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function foo(){
    var pagingButtons = document.createElement('div');

    for(var j = 0; j < pagingObjects.length; j++ )
         {         
             var pagingBtn = CreateHTMLElement("btnPaging"+j.toString(), "btnPaging", ShowPage, 'button', pagingObjects[j].value);

             pagingBtn.setAttribute('data-start', pagingObjects[j].start);
             pagingBtn.setAttribute('data-end',pagingObjects[j].end);

             pagingButtons.appendChild(pagingBtn);   
         }
    }    
         pagingArea.appendChild(table).appendChild(pagingButtons);
}

function CreateHTMLElement(id, name, onclick, type, value) {
    var HTMLElement = document.createElement('input');
    HTMLElement.id = id;
    HTMLElement.name = name;
    HTMLElement.onclick = onclick;
    HTMLElement.type = type;
    HTMLElement.value = value;
    return HTMLElement;
}
```

I need to get from **pagingArea** button with **id=btnPaging0**.

How can I implement it?

Comment: You're asking how to fetch an element by its ID?

Comment: why are you using `HTMLElement` as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("btnPaging0");
```